# coccinelle: replace single letter variables (i -> ii)

Tags: c, coccinelle

I am trying to improve readability of ca 15k lines of C code. One idea is to replace single letter variable names first with two letter names (i -> ii etc.), so one has an easier task when looking at the code. Please note that single letter variables are also in .h files.

I guess it is possible to just go use "rename variable" in one IDE or another (fixing just 3 most common ones: i, j, s; will make a difference), but if one can automate the task and do it smarter (i.e. checking that ii variable already exists somewhere, so renaming i->ii globally may be problematic).

The brain dead solution:

```
@@ identifier id=~ "^i$"; @@
- id
+ ii

@@ identifier id=~ "^j$"; @@
- id
+ jj
```

But even if I go through the whole alphabet, I will still have a problem with code already using a not so great mixture of i,ii,iii, etc.
Hence my question: are there any semantic patches doing the variable identifier renaming with checking for name conflicts/resolving these (ie by renaming pre-existing ii name to ii_qscgy: just to have most likely unique variable name)? 
Sure, I can double down on a silly code above by searching for ii,jj first, made them unique, then go for single i,j etc. but there must be a better way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Renaming `i` to `ii` doesn't make the code any more readable, because the name is still useless. Rename the variable to a more descriptive name, not longer.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Sure, but it is much easier to search in an code editor for ii than for i, no? So once I get more searchable code, I can track what it does/where ii is being changed. It is a step, not the solution.

Comment: I would think `ii` would be only be easier to search for than `i` because it's less likely to appear as part of a longer word... but usually there's a "whole words only" or similar option you can set when searching to avoid that issue, and double letters aren't more *readable* (if not using more descriptive names, I'd actually prefer eg. `i` over `ii` since it's easier to type and I won't end up wondering if the second `i` means something).

Comment: @Dmitri: Yes `ag -w i path` works nicely. But try it with letter `a`. Guys who wrote program I am looking at used it inside. Plus aa in few places. This is a reason why I wanted to go nuclear with all `i`,`j`, just in case. But maybe limiting myself to fixing `a` and `aa` will be good enough.